# How to load a spark model

Tags: apache-spark

I do not succeed in loading the model and just saved. I have got a strange error.

```py
from transforms.api import Output, transform,transform_df
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors
from pyspark.ml.classification import LogisticRegression
from pyspark.ml.classification import LogisticRegressionModel
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def save_model(spark_session, output, model, model_name='model4'):
    foundry_file_system = output.filesystem()._foundry_fs
    logger.info("The path 1 is : "+ str(foundry_file_system))
    path = foundry_file_system._root_path + "/" + model_name
    logger.info("The path 2 is : "+ str(path))
    model.write().overwrite().session(spark_session).save(path)
    model=LogisticRegressionModel.read().session(spark_session).load(path)
    df_to_predict = spark_session.createDataFrame([(
        Vectors.dense([0.0, 1.1, 0.1]),
        Vectors.dense([2.0, 1.0, -1.0]),
        Vectors.dense([2.0, 1.3, 1.0]),
        Vectors.dense([0.0, 1.2, -0.5]),)], ["features"])
    df_predicted = model.transform(df_to_predict)
    logger.info(df_predicted.show())
    logger.info(df_predicted.count())

def my_compute_function(ctx, output_model):
    training = ctx.spark_session.createDataFrame([
        (1.0, Vectors.dense([0.0, 1.1, 0.1])),
        (0.0, Vectors.dense([2.0, 1.0, -1.0])),
        (0.0, Vectors.dense([2.0, 1.3, 1.0])),
        (1.0, Vectors.dense([0.0, 1.2, -0.5]))], ["label", "features"])
    lr = LogisticRegression(maxIter=10, regParam=0.01)
    model1 = lr.fit(training)
    save_model(ctx.spark_session, output_model, model1, 'model4')
```

Here is the error I get:

> NonRetryableError: Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling
>   o266.load. : scala.MatchError:
>   [2,3,[1,null,null,WrappedArray(0.06817659473873602)],[1,1,3,null,null,WrappedArray(-3.1009356010205322,
>   2.6082147383214482, -0.38017912254303043),true],false] (of class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema)  at
>   org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegressionModel$LogisticRegressionModelReader.load(LogisticRegression.scala:1273)
>   ....

Answer (score 2):

That error is indicative of using a different method to load the model than what was used to write the model.

You should be using [LogisticRegressionModel.load](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegressionModel$@load(path:String):org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegressionModel) not LogisticRegression.read()

This can also be caused if the parquet metadata doesn't match.  I recommend that you set the summary metadata level to `NONE`

```
spark.conf.set("parquet.summary.metadata.level", "NONE")
```